# Android Device Directory issue

Tags: java, android, directory

I have an issue related to the android device file directory. I am trying to read a text file using a scanner.

line41: File f = new File("./sample/src/"+category+".txt");
line48: Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

However it is unable to find the file in the relative path that I provided. This causes it to throw a filenotfoundexception. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?
﻿
*Note: I am able to run the relative path on my laptop smoothly but it failed in my android device.

[image: Codes on my android device]
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your txt file from your project than you should put your txt file in assest folder of your project. using assest you can use that file.

Sometihg like this :

```
   AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open("myfoldername/myfilename");
File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File(my_file_name);
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

   return null;
}
```